# OS-wide equivalent of "read later" list?

Tags: shortcut

Is it possible to set up a shortcut so that whatever is in my clipboard goes into a specific text-file ?

The idea is to have an OS-wide inbox where I can send anything (img, pdf, text, url) quickly. Much like a generalized "read later" feature.

Answer (score 2):

Notes would be useful for this. There's a share extension for Notes which can be used by any app and which takes the current content straight into a note for you.

[image]

Depending on the app, the extension may be in a variety of places, but for example in Safari you can go to File → Share → Notes.